# How octave is effective in vocal range?

Tags: voice, scales, key, vocal-range, octave

My question's title seems so confusing so let me explain what I am exactly looking for.

Why some scales are different to sing in for some vocalists?
For example I have bass vocal range and my teacher says that Bm or B key is impossible for me to sing in. If I keep the scale and change the octave to lower octave, Does it affect my performance? 
Why yes or why not???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singing or not in a particular key? Your teacher needs to explain what he meant, because on the face of it, it makes no sense. The important factor is the *range* of the song, which *may* dictate what key it's best for you to sing it in, but basically your range will dictate several keys you can sing a song in.

I often hear people say " I sing in C, or G, or whatever" but it's not making any sense. Two songs could have the same range - highest and lowest notes, and be in different keys. Most decent singers will have a range  (tessitura) of more than two octaves, so your idea of singing in a different octave is a good one, provided it keeps your voice within its comfortable range.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely sing in any key you want. In fact, it is completely possible that you can sing notes just as high as any tenor would, you just might have to work a bit harder for it. I'm a tenor and my range covers about 3 octaves, from E above male high C and down. I had a vocal teacher who was a baritone or bass with about a 7 octave range (Jaime Vendera).

Even if you ignore ever increasing your range dramatically, it makes no sense that you wouldn't be able to sing in Bm. Even with only a two octave range, you can cover every single note in Bm twice. Now it may be the case that you were working on a specific song with you instructor in the key of Gm, and he doesn't think it would be possible for you to sing the same song up two whole steps to Bm at this stage. Or perhaps he had a particular song in mind that happens to be in Bm with notes that go above your current range. The song could sound drastically different with the notes being sung an octave lower, as baritone or bass singers have a very distinct tone when they sing higher notes that tenors usually can't ever pull off.

At this point i'm guessing what your instructor meant. But those are the examples where a particular song in a particular key may not be possible for you to perform **at this time.** I would ask your teacher for clarity on this, and hopefully he gives a logical answer because on the surface his point makes no sense.